# Unique number generation using shift operator and validate same with the bitwise & operator in java

Tags: java

I'm using LEFT SHIFT operator from java to generate some unique number and validate same with the bitwise & operator like below.

```
// Number generation 

public final static long UNIQUE_NUMBER8 = (long) 1 << 8; 
public final static long UNIQUE_NUMBER9 = (long) 1 << 9; 
public final static long UNIQUE_NUMBER10 = (long) 1 << 10;
```

till

```
public final static long UNIQUE_NUMBER62 = (long) 1 << 62;
```

And validation of the same, I'm doing using below condition, 
where request_number is coming from the url, which is assigned to 
url the same generated number -

```
if ( request_number >= 0 && (request_number & UNIQUE_NUMBER10) != 0){
    System.out.println("Valid");
}else{
    System.out.println("Invalid");
}
```

But using above condition i'm not able to validate numbers above 1<< 62, 
since all the numbers till 62 are being used and above it will generate 
again same numbers which are already being used and 
hence the bitwise & condition is failing.

Please help me too generate unique number using above or similar logic 
and validate same with the bitwise & operator.

Thanks

Comment: Hi. This is your **seventh** question, with respect by now you should have the hang of formatting. When you were asking your question, to the right there was a box labelled **How to Format**. Worth a read. Also, the **[?]** link above the Ask a Question box has a lot of formatting information.

Comment: Thanks for the info T.J Crowder. Next time onwards i will take care of it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You check that the number is not negative.  You can only have bits 0 to 62 set and still be non-negative.

Perhaps you should be using BitSet, you don't need all the constants and you can have almost any number of bits.

However, to generate unique id you can either create UUID, or use System.currentTimeMillis() (checking for duplicates) or just AtomicLong.incrementAndGet() depending on what type of unique id you need.

These approaches avoid the need to remember previous ids by always increasing the number used to generate the id. UUID is unique across systems but is relatively combersome, using the currentTimeMillis can be unique even if the system is restarted (and has a built in timestamp), AtomicLong is the lightest, but restarts when the system does.

Answer (score 1):

You could generate a UUID everytime you have a new request. Add it to a Set to check if its already been created/used. Thus you have an almost unlimited number of ids.

See here: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=56

Answer (score 0):

Using `BitSet` is a better option for you.